# how can control of number word show in article in frontpage

Tags: charts

I would like to limit the amount of text that show in frontpage. Is there an easy way to do 
this?

in general i do this :-

[image]

but in front page show me article as not good like this:-

[image]

its bad in style ,,, what can i do

Comment: Is your frontpage the default node listing or a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your body field within your view.

Click the **"Rewrite results"** fieldset and check **"Trim this field to a maximum length"**.

Set your maximum length and then check **"Trim only on a word boundary".**

[image]

This will prevent your body text from being cut off.